# Explanation about logcat?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I print logcat to see duration of process in app. I wonder the line of information. I have read [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html). But no clear explanation about this.

```
01-12 14:54:35.789 20802-21237/com.test.myapp E/Compare end: END
01-12 14:54:35.799 20802-21237/com.test.myapp E/Compare Start: START
```

My question is what number **20802-21237** mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are PID-TID.
PID is process ID, TID is thread id.

Comment: Thank, I am careless. It is written in the link. But there is not much information about the PID and TID. Can you explain me about it?

Comment: Every process has an ID that is given to it by the operating system. Additionally, the Java Virtual Machine uses its own implementation of concurrency using Threads. Each such thread is given an ID by the JVM. The log line states the ID of the process and the internal thread within that process that wrote that specific line to the log.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to google description about logcat:

> PID stands for process identifier and TID is thread identifier; they
> can be the same if there’s only one thread.

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat